# Omnifaces Validation

Tags: omnifaces

Is there a way to add a custom validation method when using omnifaces validation? I need a dynamic message which I generate from inside my bean.

```
public boolean  validate(FacesContext facesContext, List<UIInput> components, List<Object> values) {


    Messages.addGlobalError(customDynamicMessage);

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Which information did you miss in the examples in http://showcase.omnifaces.org/validators/validateMultiple?

Comment: @BalusC In that example it displays a  static message set via the attribute on the validateMultiple tag "You should enter 'one', 'two' and 'three' respectively." I want to be able to set the validation error message from the bean.

Comment: You basically want `message="#{bean.message}"`?

Comment: I guess I could do that...its not quite as efficient as the validation already does some complex calculations so I would have to do it again.

Comment: Before when I used the normal Faces I would through the ValidatorException with the message directly from the validation code